# Puzzle Bubble SDL game (cascade algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sdl, game-engine

I am making a puzzle bubble-like game in SDL and I am stuck on the mechanic that makes the bubbles fall when they get stuck in the air with no visible connections. Here is an example of what I mean. When I destroy the orange bubbles, all the others would fall.

[image: Example]

All the bubbles in the grid (2D vector) have a struct that determines their connections:

```
struct Neighbours
{
    Bobble* TopRight{ nullptr };
    Bobble* Right{ nullptr };
    Bobble* BottomRight{ nullptr };
    Bobble* TopLeft{ nullptr };
    Bobble* Left{ nullptr };
    Bobble* BottomLeft{ nullptr };
};
```

How would you tackle this problem? My head is telling me to use recursion, but I am not really experienced with that. I would appreciate any pseudocode or anything that might help

Comment: Go though each bubble that is considered "connected" to the top or whatever, and then implement some variation of [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). The remaining stuff is disconnected.

Comment: When a bubble is destroyed it must inform its connections about it. After this job, you can run a loop on the remaining bubbles and make unconnected ones to fall.

Comment: @Ripi2 I don't need to inform the other bubbles as I set the destroyed ones to nullptr (?)

Comment: Using raw pointers in this way is a bad idea, it's way to error-prone. Store your bubbles in a simple 2D array (where every second is row is assumed to be shifted half-a-tile).

Comment: it seems to me that you have a problem that your problem is equivalent to the connectivity of a graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the neighbours to be separate variables, it would be really easier to use some sort of a container instead:

```
std::list<Bobble*> neighbours;
```

or

```
std::vector<Bobble*> neighbours;
```

With the latter option you can acecss each neighbour easily by element index:

```
// the last enum element may be useful, or may not be
enum { TopRight, Right, BottomRight, TopLeft, Left, BottomLeft, NumElements };

// ...

// init the vector with neighbours

// ...

// access top-left
neighbours[TopLeft];
```

Now you can easily iterate over the elements (whichever container you chose to use):

```
for(Bobble* b : neighbours) {
   // do stuff...
}
```

Inside the loop, as you already guessed, you need to recursively go into each element:

```
void searchForOrange(Bobble* b, bool callerConnected)
{
    // this ensures we won't have an infinite loop
    b->setVisited(true);
    // mark b as connected if we know that the previous bubble is connected;
    // this ensures that after we find an orange, all the following
    // bubbles we go into, will also get marked as connected
    b->markAsConnected(callerConnected);

    for(Bobble* n : b->neighbours) {
        if(n != nullptr and not n->wasVisited()) {
           // check if n is an orange
           if(n->isOrange()) {
               // mark as connected to orange
               b->markAsConnected(true);
           } else {
               searchForOrange(n, b->isConnected());
               // if the path through n lead to an orange
               // then mark b as also connected; 
               // this ensures that all the bubbles in the direct backward
               // path get marked as connected
               if(n->isConnected()) {
                   b->markAsConnected(true);
               }
           }
        }
    }
   if(b->isConnected()) {
       // TODO: second loop that will, on the way back,
       //       iterate over all bubbles that were visited,
       //       but not yet marked as connected
       // ...
    }
}
```

After the first loop, if an orange bubble was eventually encountered, there may remain some bubbles that are not marked as connected, because you went into them before finding the orange one, and they turned out to be a dead end, and you don't return to them in the first loop.

That's why there should be a second recursive loop that will mark those remaining ones as well. But this one should be easy to figure out, so I'm leaving it as an excersise (hint: in the second loop, you don't need to go into bubbles that are already marked as connected - this will speed thigns up).

Comment: not really what I meant as the bubbles don't fall when I only blow an orange one, but when there is no connection all the way to the roof (first row), Thanks for the pseudocode, it gave me a hint of how to use recursion properly. I was trying to write an algorithm similar to the pseudocode you wrote. I have a backup plan (it's a uni assessment) if it doesn't work out anyway